# Implementing Double LinkedList - Maximum recursion depth when calling head node

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I've been practicing DS&A by implementing common data structures in Python, and it looks like I've done something wrong in my implementation.

Here are my Node and LinkedList classes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, prev = None, next = None):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node(Value: {self.value}, Prev: {self.prev}, Next: {self.next})"


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)

        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node

        else:
            new_node.prev = self.tail
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
```

It seems to append things just fine, but when I call `ll.head` where `ll = LinkedList()`, I run into a maximum recursion depth error.

What I expected was the repr string for the initial head Node. What am I doing wrong/not understanding correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Check for None with is `if self.head is None`

Comment: I Guess self.tail.next = new_node, self.tail = new_node is wrong...